# why am I getting this error for size() of arrays and how do I declare an array of boost::threads?

Tags: c++

I am getting this error. The function is supposed to do a mergeSort but I didn't combine it at the end. I will do that later but I want to make sure that it doesn't do the final merge at the end.

edit: I have to use #include boost/thread.hpp because the Linux server that my school uses doesn't have c++ 11

```
multi.cpp: In function 'int main()':
multi.cpp:116:29: error: request for member 'size' in 'data', which is of non-class type 'int [1000000]'
multi.cpp:116:54: error: request for member 'size' in 'data', which is of non-class type 'int [1000000]'
multi.cpp:117:32: error: expected primary-expression before 't1'
multi.cpp:117:32: error: expected ';' before 't1'
multi.cpp:120:31: error: request for member 'size' in 'data', which is of non-class type 'int [1000000]'
```

Here is my code. I am pretty sure my error is coming from the fact that I don't know how to set up an array of threads. Do I need to wait for one thread to finish before I can add another one to the array?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
using namespace std;

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r);
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r);
bool is_sorted(int* data, int size);
bool is_sorted(int* data, int size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
        if(data[i] > data[i+1])
            return false;

    return true;
}

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 =  r - m;

    /* create temp arrays */
    int L[n1], R[n2];

    /* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j];

    /* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
    i = 0; // Initial index of first subarray
    j = 0; // Initial index of second subarray
    k = l; // Initial index of merged subarray
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there
       are any */
    while (i < n1)
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there
       are any */
    while (j < n2)
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r)
    {
        // Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for
        // large l and h
        int m = l+(r-l)/2;

        // Sort first and second halves
        mergeSort(arr, l, m);
        mergeSort(arr, m+1, r);

        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}

struct my_sort{
    public:
        void operator()()
        {
            mergeSort(arr, l, r);
        }
        my_sort(){}
        my_sort(int array[], int left, int right)
        {
            arr = array;
            l = left;
            r = right;
        }


    private:
        int* arr;
        int l;
        int r;

};

int main() {
    int data[1000000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        data[i] = rand();

    unsigned threads = boost::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    boost::thread threading[threads];
    for(int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    {
        my_sort m1(data, i * data.size()/threads, i * data.size()/threads - 1);
        threading[i] = boost::thread t1{m1};
    }

    cout << is_sorted(data, data.size()-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int L[n1], R[n2];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must be defined using a constant expression to denote the number of entries, not a variable.  What you want is `std::vector<int> L1(n1), R(n2);`.  Once you use `std::vector`, then you will have the `size()` function you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
multi.cpp:116:29: error: request for member 'size' in 'data', which is of non-class type 'int [1000000]'
...
multi.cpp:120:31: error: request for member 'size' in 'data', which is of non-class type 'int [1000000]'
```

The type `int[1000000]` doesn't have a `size` method. It is a primitive type. Use `sizeof` or better yet `std::vector`. (When you have access to C++11, you can use `std::array`.)

```
multi.cpp:117:32: error: expected primary-expression before 't1'
multi.cpp:117:32: error: expected ';' before 't1'
```

...

```
threading[i] = boost::thread t1{m1};
```

This is a syntax error. Are you trying to define a variable in an expression?

Comment: I wanted to save the thread that was going to the m1 into an array so that I could call it whenever I wanted to but I don't know if I am doing it correctly or how to do it.

Comment: @JasonPham You don't need to create a `boost::thread` variable; just call the constructor on the right side of the assignment operator: `threading[i] = boost::thread{m1}`.

Comment: The other issue is that `int[1000000]` would and can blow out the stack in many compilers.  Better to suggest `std::vector` and stay away from local arrays declared this large.

Comment: @JasonPham -- *it compiled* --.  It will *not* compile with an ANSI compilant compiler.  Read the comment I made in the main section.  If this is supposed to be a school project, your code uses Variable Length Arrays, which are **not** part of C++, but an extension offered by the compiler you're using.  Using extensions, from what I see, are usually not allowed by teachers.